# How to change comments in excel file with go

Tags: go, comments, excelize

I'm using the excelize library.

```golang
newfile, _ := excelize.OpenFile("filename.xlsx")

println(newfile.GetComments())
//map[Sheet1:[{Author 0 A2 comment1}]]

_ = newfile.InsertRow("Sheet1", 1)

println(newfile.GetComments())
//map[Sheet1:[{Author 0 A2 comment1}]]
```

the coordinates of my comment `comment1` have not changed. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The comment is bound to a cell. When you insert a new row, the call above still contains the comment.
If you would like a comment in the second row, you have to set the comment explizit.